# False if the variable is changing, true if the variable is not changing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

How to make C# code in Unity when boolean variable is False if the variable is changing, True if the variable is not changing.
So in the first frame I have myBool = true, in the second myBool = false. And if it's happening, myBool2 = false.
But, if myBool = true all the time, then myBool2 = true. 
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must test this condition before changing the variable you want to observe.

```
bool notChanging = newBoolValue == someBool;
someBool = newBoolValue;
```

It would be easier with a property

```
public bool NotChanging { get; private set; };

private bool _someBool;
public bool SomeBool
{
    get { return _someBool; }
    set {
        NotChanging  = value == _someBool;
        _someBool = value;
    }
}
```

Now, you can simply set the property and the change state will automatically be set accordingly.

```
SomeBool = newBoolValue;
```